# Problem in receiving data from BNO085 over I2C interfaced with SAMD21

Tags: c, embedded, sensors, microchip, samd21

I have interfaced BNO085 with SAMD21G18A controller via I2C synchronous communication running at 100KHz on SERCOM1 of controller and processor is running at 8MHz.
I am trying to read Gyroscope and Accelerometer's data using SHTP protocol ([reference manual](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/4/d/9/3/8/SH-2-Reference-Manual-v1.2.pdf)). which the sensor employs.

*Here's how I am doing the I2C initialization:*

```cpp
    i2c_m_sync_get_io_descriptor(&SYS_I2C_BUS, &io);
    i2c_m_sync_enable(&SYS_I2C_BUS);
    i2c_m_sync_set_slaveaddr(&SYS_I2C_BUS, I2C_Address_of.IMU_BNO, I2C_M_SEVEN); //Address = 0x68
```

When I try to receive data, I always get the following packet:

[image]

From this [reference manual](https://www.micro-semiconductor.com/datasheet/b2-BNO080.pdf), we can see that it is an advertisement channel of BNO085, It confirms that the communication is established with the controller.
I tried soft resetting BNO085 using

```cpp
    shtpData[0] = 1;
    BNO085_send_packet(CHANNEL_EXECUTABLE, 1);  //CHANNEL_EXECUTABLE = 1, size = 1
```

and I have turned the mode to 'ON' to take it out of sleep mode using

```cpp
    shtpData[0] = 2; 
    BNO085_send_packet(CHANNEL_EXECUTABLE, 1);  //CHANNEL_EXECUTABLE = 1, size = 1
```

When I try to read the Product_ID report using `SHTP_REPORT_PRODUCT_ID_REQUEST`(0xf9) I do not receive anything of the data rather the same thing as the above image.

Here's a link of my I2C probing using logic analyser-> [Waveforms](https://ufile.io/ufi5uvjo)

What am I missing and how to read the correct data from BNO085?